# Ctrl backspace / left / right are not working as expected in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

It suddenly happens when I found these combinations are not jumping per word. Looks like my Notepad++ don't think space is a delimiter of word anymore...

For example, when I use these keyboard shortcuts to move in following sentence:

```
# Set this to true to report blocked/re-test errors
 ^                                  ^  ^           ^   <-- cursor only stops at these positions
```

This behavior is only seen in Notepad++, I had tried other applications like Notepad, they are working fine.

Is there any option in Notepad++ to solve this issue?

Comment: After restarting notepad++ it's working fine now. I had also found a [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/993b6ab9/) discussing word delimiters.

Comment: I just had the same phenomenon, and restarting it worked here, too.